# Setting to trust all certificates with Apache Axis

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, https, certificate

I am using auto-generated (wsdl2Java) `org.apache.axis.client` to connect to external web service and fetch some data. Connection is over SSL, but their certificate has expired. They did get a new one, though somehow, somewhere their old certificate got cached on my server because I'm getting `PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed`. And I only get this error on my server, when I run the web app on my local machine it works fine, their current certificate gets picked up. Killing all Java processes and restarting Tomcat on server didn't work, so I'm trying to set it to always trust certificates, but that's not working either.

`AxisProperties.setProperty("org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory", "org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");` or `AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory", "org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");` should work from what I'm seeing on the internet. I'm still getting the same error.

Can I somehow set it per call? I've got `org.apache.axis.client.Call` and invoke is called on it.

```
org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
_call.setOperation(_operations[1]);
_call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
_call.setSOAPActionURI("");
_call.setEncodingStyle(null);
_call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
_call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
_call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
_call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "CreateOperation"));

setRequestHeaders(_call);
setAttachments(_call);
try {        
    java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {requestArg});

    if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
        throw (java.rmi.RemoteException)_resp;
    }
...
```

Comment: Certificates are not cached. The remote may be behind a load balancer and all instances may not have been updated with the newer certificate. Except of course if you added explicitly yourself the old certificate as trusted in your own trust store...

Comment: @Patrick I didn't add their old certificate to my trust store. I did add their new certificate in hopes of making it work but it still uses the old one. Thanks for your input.